# JavaScript Code gives out of memory exception

Tags: javascript, out-of-memory

i have an issue with javascript.
   `var startTime = Date.now(); while ((Date.now() - startTime) < 30000) { display(); }`
when i adding these lines of code and trying to run my script,it gives me an error: out of memory.

my original code is:

```
<script>
   var startTime = Date.now();
while ((Date.now() - startTime) < 30000) {
    display();
}
        function display() {
            setTimeout(showLeft, 1000);
            setTimeout(showRight, 2000);
            setTimeout(showBLeft, 3000);
            setTimeout(showBRight, 4000);
            setTimeout(clearAllDiv, 6000);
        }

        function showLeft() {
            document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "Hızlı";
        }
        function showRight() {
            document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = "Oku";
        }
        function showBLeft() {
            document.getElementById("bleft").innerHTML = "Çabuk";
        }
        function showBRight() {
            document.getElementById("bright").innerHTML = "Anla";
        }

        function clearAllDiv() {
            document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = " ";
            document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = " ";
            document.getElementById("bleft").innerHTML = " ";
            document.getElementById("bright").innerHTML = " ";
        }
    </script>
```

i want to repeat my display function for 30 seconds.
when i change 30.000 to 1.000 it works fine,but i need 30 seconds not 1 second.

EDIT:
i was creating infinite loop,and due this reason i got out of memory exception.

Comment: `display` doesn't wait for the timers to expire. It returns immediately, and then the next iteration creates more timers and more and more ... and they never get a chance to expire. Your loop is a blocking loop. Only after the loop finishes can the timer callback functions start to execute.

Comment: you have created an infinite loop

Comment: In just a few seconds, your loop will have started tens of thousands of timers. That's what's using up memory.

Comment: @trincot thank you for information,i am newbie in stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have created an infinite loop. maybe something more like this:

```
var startTime = Date.now();
checkTimer(startTime);

function checkTimer(startTime) {
    if(((Date.now() - startTime) < 30000)) {
      display();
      setTimeout(() => {
        checkTimer(startTime)
      }, 1000);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is blocking the asynchronous execution of the timer callbacks, and in the mean while your loop creates a **huge** amount of timers, running out of memory.

Instead you could schedule also the `display` calls, like this:

```js
// Execute display 4 times, but only at the right time
display();
setTimeout(display, 8000);
setTimeout(display, 16000);
setTimeout(display, 24000);

function display() {
    setTimeout(showLeft, 1000);
    setTimeout(showRight, 2000);
    setTimeout(showBLeft, 3000);
    setTimeout(showBRight, 4000);
    setTimeout(clearAllDiv, 6000);
}

function showLeft() {
    document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = "Hızlı";
}
function showRight() {
    document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = "Oku";
}
function showBLeft() {
    document.getElementById("bleft").innerHTML = "Çabuk";
}
function showBRight() {
    document.getElementById("bright").innerHTML = "Anla";
}

function clearAllDiv() {
    document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = " ";
    document.getElementById("right").innerHTML = " ";
    document.getElementById("bleft").innerHTML = " ";
    document.getElementById("bright").innerHTML = " ";
}
```

```html
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="bleft"></div>
<div id="bright"></div>
```